# How to limit the browsers' search functionality to the contents of a Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, browser, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use a Bootstrap Modal on my page and I would like to limit the scope of the browsers' search functionality (Ctrl + f) to the contents of the Bootstrap Modal. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible. Browser search work over DOM, so the only way to make browser don't find something is to remove it from DOM or use `display:none` which actually also removes element from DOM. Even `opacity: 0` or `visibility: hidden` don't help.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that. What I will do now is use a different kind of overlay (full page instead of Bootstrap Modal). Then I use `$('#content_in_the_background').hide();` and `$('#content_in_the_background').show();` to remove the contents temporally when the overlay is open.